# Hold'em hand history with hero

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand-history, statistics

I'm looking for a significant number of hold'em hands with hero as I'm doing some specific statistical analyses and having hole cards only when they are shown at showdown creates some significant bias (e.g. what is your empirical % chance to see the showdown if you're at preflop with a particular hand).

Unfortunately all hand histories offered by dedicated websites don't have any hero (i.e. they don't have the hole card of 1 player from the start of the hand, even if he folds). The 10mln IRC hands from University of Alberta do also not include any hero.

Would anyone have any hints / idea on how I could find hands with heros?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

This information is not supposed to be public because no player would want to have their playstyle completely analyzed.

Something you can do is approach players directly(maybe via forums like http://www.pokerstrategy.com/forum/) and ask is someone is willing to share his/her stats with you. I doubt that any pros would ever do that but if you explain why you need it there might be some people willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

The computer poker competition provides logs including hole cards of players. Unfortunately there are heads-up and 3 player games between computers only.

http://www.computerpokercompetition.org/downloads/competitions/